# Delphi 2010 variant to unicode problem

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, variant

I am working on a DLL in Delphi 2010. It exports a procedure that receives an array of variants. I want to be able to take one of these variants, and convert it into a string, but I keep getting ?????

I cannot change the input variable - it HAS to be an array of variants.
The host app that calls the DLL cannot be changed. It is written in Delphi 2006.

Sample DLL code:

```
Procedure TestArr(ArrUID : array of variant); stdcall;  
var 
  i: integer;  
  s: string;
begin  
  s:= string(String(Arruid[0]));  
  showmessage(s);  
end;
```

Using D2006 my DLL works fine. I have tried using `VartoStr` - no luck. When I check the `VarType` I am getting a `varString`. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You host application is sending an `AnsiString` and you dll is expecting a `UnicodeString`.
Unicode strings was introduced in Delphi 2009, it does not exist in Delphi 2006. How to fix it? Try [untested]:

```
Procedure TestArr(ArrUID : array of variant); stdcall;  
var 
  i: integer;  
  s: AnsiString;
begin  
  s:= Ansistring(VarToStr(Arruid[0]));  
  showmessage(s);  
end;
```

or maybe [also untested]:

```
Procedure TestArr(ArrUID : array of variant); stdcall;  
var 
  i: integer;  
  s: AnsiString;
begin  
  s:= Ansistring(AnsiString(Arruid[0]));  
  showmessage(s);  
end;
```

You can also check if theres is a function Like `VarToStr` that accepts `AnsiStrings` (maybe in the `AnsiStrings` unit?).

Comment: You can't use ShareMem to solve problems between D2006 and D2010 related to Unicode/Ansi. They use totally different forms of the memory manager.

Comment: @Ken White you are right, my mistake. I forgot that embarcadero changed the memory manager also (now it uses fastmm).

Answer (score 0):

1/ How have you call the `VarToStr()` function ? `VarToString(Arruid[0])` ?

2/ Does your Delphi2006 Application send AnsiString or WideString to the DLL ?
  If so, and if (1) is not working, try to cast to `AnsiString` instead of `string`.